# Abort and restart batch execution

Tags: python, loops, batch-file, execution

I have a python program that I run with a batch-file to store all the launch parameters. The program runs in an endless loop. I'd like to abort the python loop after 10 minutes and restart the python program again. How can I achieve this in a bat-file? Are there better solutions?
Calls, quits and exits don't seem to work with nerver ending programs.

Cheers!

Comment: When you say you want to restart the program I presume that you want to change the *state* of the program to what it was when you first started it. Why not do this in the script itself and put everything in a while loop that waits for 10 minutes before each iteration?

Comment: Show your code. See `timeout /?` and `taskkill /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Show your code....
Can get better help that way.
Try `Taskkill /?` or `timeout /?`, and `start`.
For example:
`Taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F
timeout 10 >nul
start notepad.exe`

Answer (score 0):

```
:test
python <your script>
taskkill /F /IM python.exe /T
goto:test
```

You can do it in the above way, but it is good to do everything in python using while loops.